# rmagick cannot change font-family

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I tried this example here:
http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html#annotation

But I can only generate this image.

[image]

Which looks different from the image generated on that page:
[image]

And even when I change font_family to anything else, output image remains the same. What gives?

I use ruby-1.8.7-p249 and rmagick-2.12.2 and rmagick-2.13.1.

Comment: Have you `helvetica` font installed? Did you try other fonts?

Comment: Having the same problem. Might be explained here: http://def-end.com/post/1599618417/only-default-font-is-available-in-rmagick

Answer (score 3):

Pass a full path of the font file (i've used ttf/otf) into the font attribute instead of changing the font family.
This way you can also use a font that is not installed on your system.

Comment: I tried changing the font using the file also, but it not getting changed.